# Factor is too large

Tags: utilities

I'm trying to use a `factor` utility but it tells me that number is too large. Is there any utility that can do what `factor` doing but not tells that number is too large?

Comment: How large is the number?

Comment: It is a `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141` in decimal, 78 characters in length.

Comment: May be it is a system config/capacity issue. Works for me: $ factor 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337
115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337: 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Don't know why it's not working on my as working on yours.

Comment: @hiprivet: You are running 32-bit or 64-bit machine?

Comment: @Gnouc: 32-bit, with i686-pae kernel.

Comment: You can use ruby. Ruby has the ability to handle obscenely long numbers. `require 'prime'; puts(0xffffdeadbeef.prime_division.inspect)`.

Comment: Do not use prime_division.inspect in ruby. It is extremely slow! factor.pl from Math::Prime::Util is OK, or use Pari/GP's factor function. For instance, try on: 806578020551755900412008880903137528217525975284037923

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe your `factor` is not built with `GMP`, so it can not handle number bigger than `2**64-1`:

```
$ factor 18446744073709551616
factor: `18446744073709551616' is too large
$ factor 18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615: 3 5 17 257 641 65537 6700417
```

Running this command to check if `factor` built with `GMP`:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/factor 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffda1fe000)
        libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007faae00f5000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007faadfd46000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007faae037c000)
```

The limit may be higher on some machines (the number has to fit in `uintmax_t` type), but your number is a 256-bit number, and no common machine supports such a big `uintmax_t`, if any.

Note that the `factor` utility can be compiled with [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) support. In that case, there is effectively no limit on the size of the number. It appears that your distribution hasn't activated GMP support (which makes sense since it would add a dependency on an extra library to a core system package for a rarely used feature).

If you have `perl`, you can try `factor.pl` program include in `Math::Prime::Util` module:

```
$ /home/cuonglm/.cpan/build/Math-Prime-Util-0.31-9c_xq3/bin/factor.pl 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337
115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337: 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337
```

Comment: By this logic, `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141` shouldn't work even on a 64-bit system as that's WAY bigger than 64 bit. (and indeed it doesn't on my system, which is 64-bit)

Comment: @gnouc, that should be: can not handle number larger than `2**32-1`

Comment: @Patrick: No, it's not the logic here. `factor` can work on arbitrary-precision numbers. In `info factor`, you can see that factor works well with number up to `2**64-1`. I see in `factor` source that it uses `uintmax_t`, which is always 64 bits.

Comment: @Gnouc That just supports my argument. OP's number is WAY bigger than `2**64-1`.

Comment: @Patrick: I don't understand what you mean. `factor` can work with arbitrary-precision, it's mean that with number bigger than `2**64-1`. But in 32-bit machine, it causes long integer overflow when number greater than `2**64-1`.

Comment: `file $(which factor)`: `/usr/bin/factor: ELF 64-bit LSB executable`. `factor 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337`: `factor: ‘115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337’ is too large`.

Comment: @Patrick: What is output of `ldd /usr/bin/factor`?

Comment: @Gnouc `linux-vdso.so.1` `libc.so.6` `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

Comment: @Patrick: Oh, your `factor` does not buid with `GNU MP`, so it can not handle arbitrary-precision numbers. See `info factor` for more details.

Comment: Newer versions of factor in coreutils use 2 uint64_t's, or GMP if chosen when compiled. The maximum it can handle on my 64-bit ubuntu system is 2^127-1, so apparently it wasn't built with GMP.

Comment: @Gnouc But going back to my very first statement, the machine architecture has nothing to do with that big long number. If the code can handle numbers larger than the CPU type, then it doesn't matter if it's 64-bit, 32-bit, or 8-bit.

Comment: @Patrick: No, you can check in `factor` source, it use `xstrtoumax` to convert string to integer, and will raise `LONGINT_OVERFLOW` if it can't. I have tested in 32-bit machine and it always raises error.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: In my `openSUSE 64-bit`, `% factor 170141183460469231731687303715884105727
170141183460469231731687303715884105727: 170141183460469231731687303715884105727`

Comment: @richard No: `factor` supports 64-bit numbers on most 32-bit platforms.

Comment: Compiled with GMP, still gives the "is too large" error. I used pari/GP (`apt-get install pari-gp`, then run `gp`) as mentioned in another answer. That factored it in about one second.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `factor` from the coreutils. However it needs to be compiled with bignum support. FYI, this is not the case with the binary that comes with some distributions, such as Debian ([bug 608832](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=608832)). But you can download the source and recompile it after installing GMP (which is used by default if found).

Another solution is to use Pari/GP (well-known for number theory):

```
? factor(806578020551755900412008880903137528217525975284037923)
%1 =
[ 238366085426200783161668947 1]

[3383778439410064898661524209 1]
```

With this number, it takes a few seconds.

Comment: +1 for pari/GP, it computed the factors in about a second (single-threaded it seems) while other programs took multiple minutes multi-threaded. I had not heard of the tool before. Tip for others: `apt-get install pari-gp` then run `gp`, at least in Debian Stretch.